# Scheme: pattern matching syntax

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, syntax-error, racket

I am trying to write a pattern match for calls to let like this:

```
(define let→λ&call
  (match-lambda (`(let ((,<var> ,<val>) . (,<vars> ,<vals>)) ,<expr> . ,<exprs>)
                   `((λ ,<var> . ,<vars> . ,<expr> . ,<exprs>) ,<val> . ,<vals>))))
```

But I am having two problems that I can't solve.

1) The intperter complains about the "." in:

```
,<expr> . ,<exprs>
```

in the matching section

2) Calls to let→λ&call (with the offending "." removed) like:

```
(let→λ&call ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) (displayln x) (displayln y) (displayln z))
```

get a complaint about referencing an identifier, "x", before its definition -- which seems unavoidable.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Okay, here is the complete, more interesting problem.

I have written a function **match-rewriter** which is just match-lambda except that it returns its argument if no match is found.

Using match rewriter I want to be able to write rules that can be passed to another function **rewrite** which is this:

```
#| (rewrite rule s) repeatedly calls unary function 'rule' on every "part" 
    of s-expr s, in unspecified order, replacing each part with result of rule, 
    until calling rule makes no more changes to any part. 
     Parts are s, elements of s, and (recursively) parts of the elements of s. (define (rewrite rule s) |#

  (let* ([with-subparts-rewritten
          (if (list? s) (map (λ (element) (rewrite rule element)) s) s)]
         [with-also-rule-self (rule with-subparts-rewritten)])
    (if (equal? with-also-rule-self with-subparts-rewritten)
        with-also-rule-self
        (rewrite rule with-also-rule-self))))
```

Here is an example of proper usage:

```
(define arithmetic 
   (match-rewriter (`(+ ,a ,b) (+ a b)) 
                (`(* ,a ,b) (* a b)) 
                ))
(rewrite arithmetic '(+ (* 2 (+ 3 4)) 5))
```

==>

```
19
```

Now I have written:

```
(define let→λ&call
  (match-rewriter (`(let ((,<var> ,<val>) . (,<vars> ,<vals>)) ,<expr> . ,<exprs>)
                   `((λ (,<var> . ,<vars>) ,<expr> . ,<exprs>) ,<val> . ,<vals>))))
```

to implement lets as lambda calls, but this is how it is behaving:

```
(rewrite let→λ&call '(let((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) (displayln x) (displayln y) (displayln z)))
'((λ (x y 2)
    (displayln x)
    (displayln y)
    (displayln z))
  1
  z
  3)
```

which, I have to say, really has me stumped.  Strangely this call:

```
(rewrite let→λ&call '(let((w 0) (x 1) (y 2) (z 3)) (displayln w) (displayln x) (displayln y) (displayln z)))
'(let ((w 0) (x 1) (y 2) (z 3))
   (displayln w)
   (displayln x)
   (displayln y)
   (displayln z))
```

Just returns its argument, meaning that match-rewriter did not find a match for this pattern.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with Scheme macros or syntax-related features before, but from what I know of Scheme, what you wrote:

```
(λ ,<var> . ,<vars> . ,<expr> . ,<exprs>)
```

makes no sense, because your "pair" (which is created with dots) actually contains 4 elements. Did you mean to make a list?

Comment: You are right.  The problem with the "." was solved by rewriting the match as (λ (,<var> . ,<vars>) (,<expr> . ,<exprs>))